# Correct configuration for a mono hosted wcf service using ajax and json

Tags: c#, ajax, json, wcf, mono

I am making a WCF service to be hosted on mono (CentOS 6.5) where methods are called from a html client using ajax and json. But I can't get a simple example working.

Whenever I call my method, the service responds with an error: "Expected content-type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' but got 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'".

Can somebody tell if there is something wrong in my configuration, or does mono just not support something I'm using here? I read somewhere that if there's a binding mismatch the wcf defaults to text/xml, but I don't see what's wrong in my binding configuration.

This is my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: 'http://PU.BL.IC.IP/wcf/DataService.svc/GetCustomers")',
  data: '{"prefix": "' + $("#value").val() + '"}',
  processData: false,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (response) {
    console.log('success');
    //Do something with the result
  },
  error: function (a, b, c) {
    // NOTE: here is where I get the error, so I know the service itself and sending the query to it works.
    console.log('error');
    console.log('Service call failed: ' + a.status + ' ' + a.statusText);
  }
});
```

Here's my interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IDataService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string GetCustomers(string prefix);
}
```

Here's my service implementation:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class DataService : IDataService
{
    public string GetCustomers(string prefix)
    {
        List<object> customers = new List<object>();

        customers.Add(new
        {
            Id = "1",
            Name = "Customer Name",
        });

        return (new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(customers));
    }
}
```

And here's my entire web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <httpRuntime/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webscriptBehavior">
          <enableWebScript/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior" name="DataService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IDataService" behaviorConfiguration="webscriptBehavior"/>
      </service>
    </services>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Thanks everyone,
Olli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decorate your method with the RequestFormat attribute and set it to JSON.

```
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
```

Alternatively send your request as xml, which is the default format.